# How to delete the build cache while building documents using WebSupport.Build in sphinx?

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

Is there any way to delete the build cache while using `WebSupport.build` as in `make clean` in Sphinx? I need to delete the build cache because if the image with the same name but different image content is built one or more time using `WebSupport.build` the same old image will be shown unless and until the name of the image is changed.

I am using `Websupport.build` to build docs from `rst` format like as:

```
from sphinxcontrib.websupport import WebSupport
support = WebSupport(srcdir=srcdir, builddir=builddir,search="xapian")
support.build()
document= support.getdocument("index")
```

and render accordingly in `flask` application

with following `jinja` template:

```
{% extends 'baselayout.html' %}

{% block doc_sidebar %}
    {{ document.sidebar|safe }}
{% endblock %}

{% block doc_content %}
    {{ document.body|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sanity check: is the image cached in the web browser or on the file system? If the latter, you could always invoke `make clean` via an [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system) call before building.

Comment: Its cached in the file system. What do you mean by invoking`make clean` via `os.system` call before building please elaborate? You meant to remove `builddir`  before each build?

Comment: Yes. Import `os`, then craft a command to pass into its method. I linked to the Python 3 docs for `os` earlier for more information.

Comment: I suggest using `shutil.rmtree(builddir)` to remove `builddir`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I have found working for me: Removing `builddir` if it exists only to remove the previous build.

```
import os
import shutil
from sphinxcontrib.websupport import WebSupport

def build_doc(srcdir, builddir):
    if os.path.exists(builddir):
        shutil.rmtree(builddir)
    support = WebSupport(srcdir=srcdir, builddir=_builddir,search="xapian")
    support.build()
```

Thank you, Everyone!!!